# Authentication required

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to run a `.sh` file, in between a pop up appears, asking me to put password to authenticate.

Though I put the right password (Password which I use to login in), but still the pop up does not accept it and remains there.

See the screen shot.

[image: screenshot]

How to resolve the issue?

Comment: We do not know what and from where you are trying to download. But anyway [`qtiplot` is packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=qtiplot) and [`kicad` too](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=kicad). What is "candle" - I do not know. Please post text instead of image with links to make your problem reproducible.